# Caching a function view for a day

Tags: python, cache, flask

I am writing a flask app that I will deploy it on Heroku to test it. There is a page that will generate daily photos and information based on a JSON file. The view is valid for 24 hours beginning from 00:00 to 23:59 of everyday.

I am thinking about using a cache, otherwise the app will consume unnecessary resources.

```
import ..


TODAY = date.today()

 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.jinja_env.auto_reload = False
 cache = Cache(config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple', 'CACHE_ARGS' : TODAY})
#This function reads a json file, filter the daily data to process and render a html template with photos and text .

# 3600 *  24 = 86400
@cache.cached(timeout=86400)
@app.route('/inf')
def inf():
    input_file = open(os.path.join(__location__, 'json/output.json'));    
    j = json.loads(input_file.read().decode("utf-8-sig"))
    etc ..

    return render_template('inf.html', 
                        title = title,
                        config={'environment_args':{'autoescape':False}},
                        zipped =zipped) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if TODAY != cache.config['CACHE_ARGS'] :
        with app.app_context():
            cache.clear()                
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 33507))
    app.run(debug = True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

I am not sure if this is the best solution to cache the view for a day.  That's why I am asking here for more suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Why not take advantage of the RESTful architecture of the internet? I suggest you have the code generate a static page and set the expires header on that resource (or set of resources) to the end of that day (considering your audience's time zones, I guess). [This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers) might help.

Sorry, if I had experience with heroku or flask I would provide code or more details.

Comment: A lot of activity out of you recently, feel free to come join us on our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) sometime! :)